# Setting time ranges in lightning:input type=time

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

Is it possible to set the time intervals when using lighting-input tag of type="time"? The default gives intervals with 15 minutes (12:00, 12:15, 12:30... etc). But I need it to set the intervals to 30 mins each (12:00. 12:30, 01:00 .. and so on).

```
<lightning-input type="time" name="" label="Time" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is not possible - 15 minutes is hardcoded and can`t be changed in the base component. If you require such functionality you would have to implement a custom component